# get video bitrate ladder using Youtube Data API

Tags: youtube-api

I have a list of videos that I'm not their owner and I need to find their bitrate ladder. Please let me know how can I obtain the video bitrate ladder by using Youtube Data API?
I've tried the list.fileDetails but I got the 403 error with following message:
"The request is not properly authorized to access video file or processing information. Note that the `fileDetails`, `processingDetails`, and `suggestions` parts are only available to that video's owner."
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @alireza-erfanian, welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please tell us what you have tried and the issue you are having, so it's easier for someone to answer your question. Kindly have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask a good question.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Alireza Erfanian, the YouTube Data API does not provide the info you're looking for.